# Validar RFC en Funcion SQL SERVER con Expresiones Regulares

Tags: sql-server

he validado el RFC en Python y con JS pero ahora me han pedido que se haga una funcion en SQL SERVER esto para "mejorar", pero al ejecutar la funcion esta me regresa un 0 siendo que en las otras tecnologias si ha funcionado.

Este es mi codigo

```
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[ValidaRFC]    Script Date: 02/24/2022 16:31:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ValidaRFC] 
(
    @RFC as VARCHAR(50)
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @R INT
    DECLARE @LSTR INT
    DECLARE @RBIT BIT
    DECLARE @FRS VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @SRS VARCHAR(100)
    
    SELECT @LSTR = LEN(@RFC)
    SELECT @RBIT = 0
    SELECT @FRS = '%^(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13578]|[1][02])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][01])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})([0][13456789]|[1][012])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][0])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([02468][048]|[13579][26])[0][2]([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|(([A-ZÑ&]{4})([0-9]{2})[0][2]([0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-8])([A-Z0-9]{3}))$%'
    SELECT @SRS = '%^(([A-ZÑ&]{3})([0-9]{2})([0][13578]|[1][02])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][01])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|(([A-ZÑ&]{3})([0-9]{2})([0][13456789]|[1][012])(([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])|[3][0])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|(([A-ZÑ&]{3})([02468][048]|[13579][26])[0][2]([0][1-9]|[12][\\d])([A-Z0-9]{3}))|(([A-ZÑ&]{3})([0-9]{2})[0][2]([0][1-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-8])([A-Z0-9]{3}))$%'
    
    IF @LSTR = 13 OR @LSTR = 10
        IF @RFC LIKE @FRS
            SELECT @RBIT = 1

    IF @LSTR = 10
        IF @RFC LIKE @SRS
            SELECT @RBIT = 1
            
    RETURN @RBIT
END
```

Como pueden ver no es muy complicada solo ver la longitud del string y saber a donde mandarlo, pero no se si T-SQL tenga una funcion o metodo como match (hasta donde se es LIKE, lo he intentado pero no me resulta)

Espero y me puedan orientar

Comment: Como bien dices en `TSQL` no hay expresiones regulares. Se pueden incorporar utilizando funciones `CLR`. [Clr Regex](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6529/sql-server-regex-clr-function/). Si lo necesitas validar con like, quizá tengas que exponer, las posibles entradas y la salida esperada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El lenguaje T-SQL tiene una versión muy limitada de expresiones regulares. Sin embargo, puedes obtener la validación con los recursos a tu disposición. La validación de un RFC solo requiere que tenga letras y números bajo un cierto patrón. Al parecer, estás validando el puro patrón sin guiones, lo cual facilita mucho las cosas.

Te dejo una función que hace lo que requieres en un método más enfocado a SQL.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ValidaRFC] 
(
    @RFC as VARCHAR(15) --No necesitas que sea tan largo
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(  SELECT *
                FROM(VALUES(10, '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', 5), --Persona física sin homoclave
                           (13, '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]', 5), --Persona física con homoclave
                           (12, '[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]', 4) --Persona moral (siempre lleva homoclave)
                           )x(longitud, patron, iniciofecha)
                WHERE longitud = LEN( @RFC) -- Escoge cual patrón usar
                AND   @RFC LIKE patron -- Valida que el RFC cumpla con el patrón de letras y números
                AND   TRY_CONVERT( date, SUBSTRING( @RFC, iniciofecha, 6), 12) IS NOT NULL -- Valida que la fecha sea real
               )
        RETURN CAST( 1 AS bit);
    ELSE 
        RETURN CAST( 0 AS bit);
END
```